# Setting up Angular service in Controller using routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following:

```
 when('/admin/foo', {
        controller: FooListCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'frontend/partials/admin/foo-list.html',
        resolve: {
            aliasNames: ['printingService', function(printingService){
                return printingService.listArray(????);
            }]
        }
    }).
```

The controller:

```
function FooListCtrl($scope, Restangular, aliasNames) {
    $scope.aliasNames= aliasNames;
}
```

The printingService:

```
app.service('printingService', [function() {

return {
    listArray: function(theArray) {
        var result= "{";
        result += theArray.join(", ");
        result += "}";
        return result;
    }
};
}]);
```

Im my html page, I have an ng-repeat, and each object in the repeat has an array, so I'm wondering how I call the service using each object's array. The ng-repeat will loop over objects that have an array, and I need to pass each array into the service, for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">{{obj.names}}</div>
```

How do I pass each obj.names into the printingService?

Comment: there are some very strange things going on in your code ( as well as descriptions). What is the initial source of your data? Also note that global functions are no longer supported as angular controllers, should register as component of module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the reference of the service in your controller's scope and invoke it from the view :

JS: 
    function FooListCtrl($scope, Restangular, aliasNames, printingService) {
        $scope.aliasNames= aliasNames;
        $scope.printingService = printingService;
    }

And then in HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">{{printingService.listArray(obj.names)}}</div>
```